# Form freezes despite using BackgroundWorker unless we add a fake sleep

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, listbox, backgroundworker

I have successfully made my `BackgroundWorker` do its job on my `WinForm`. It works fine, but in reality it does not. As can be seen below, my form has a `listbox` as well as a `Progress Bar`. And I'm using both of them to display the progress of writing a list of recipients on a file in a `for loop`. I know this process runs way too fast. With every write of a line, the `listbox` displays a "*Adding x out of y recipients*" message and deletes the last entry of itself so that there won't be too much text. Also with every insert, the `progress bar` has to make a step.

[image]

The program works fine when I add a 1ms delay in every write by using one `Thread.Sleep(1)`. My form can still be moved around the desktop and the form looks normal. But when I remove this sleep (which is the real scenario), the form freezes as if I have never used a parallel `BackgroundWorker` to begin with. How can I overcome this issue?

Here are my BackgroundWorker's `DoWork()` and `ProgressChanged()` events respectively:

**DoWork:**

```
private void backgroundWorkerConvertDatatableToFile_DoWork(object sender, 
                                                           DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                            Select(column => column.ColumnName);
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(GetDelimiter(campaignOutputFormat), columnNames));
        backgroundWorkerConvertDatatableToFile.ReportProgress(-1, 
                                   dt.Rows.Count.ToString() + " recipients found.");
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
           IEnumerable<string> fields = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.Select(
                                                    field => field.ToString());
           sb.AppendLine(string.Join(GetDelimiter(campaignOutputFormat), fields));
           backgroundWorkerConvertDatatableToFile.ReportProgress(i, 
            string.Format("Adding {0} of {1}...", (i + 1).ToString(), dt.Rows.Count));
           Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
        string outputFile = String.Format("{0}\\{1}.csv", 
                                            campaignOutputPath, campaignFileName);
        backgroundWorkerConvertDatatableToFile.ReportProgress(0, "Writing to file..");
        File.WriteAllText(outputFile, sb.ToString());
        convertSuccess = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, 
                   "FileCampaignRunner: ConvertDataTableToCSV", ex.Message);
        convertSuccess = false;
    }
    if (convertSuccess)
    {
        backgroundWorkerConvertDatatableToFile.ReportProgress(100, 
                                               "Write to file successful!");
    }
    else
    {
        backgroundWorkerConvertDatatableToFile.ReportProgress(100, 
                                               "Error writing to file.");
    }
}
```

**ProgressChanged:**

```
private void backgroundWorkerConvertDatatableToFile_ProgressChanged(object sender,
                                                    ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.ProgressPercentage)
    {
        case -1:
            listBoxMessages.Items.Add(e.UserState.ToString());
            listBoxMessages.Items.Add("");
            break;
        case 100:
            listBoxMessages.Items.RemoveAt(listBoxMessages.Items.Count - 1);
            listBoxMessages.Items.Add(e.UserState.ToString());
            break;
        default:
            listBoxMessages.Items.RemoveAt(listBoxMessages.Items.Count - 1);
            listBoxMessages.Items.Add(string.Format(e.UserState.ToString()));
            progressBar.PerformStep();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does 'it freezes' mean: You can't use it anymore or it doesn't show progress maybe because it doesn't have time to do so?

Comment: @TaW it becomes unresponsive. I cannot drag the window around and it goes white.

Answer (score 5):

That's entirely normal when you call ReportProgress() too often.  A *firehose problem*, you are asking the UI thread to do more work then it is capable of doing.  As soon as it executed one delegate target then another one is available, it can never catch up.  It now stops doing its *other* duties, responding to input and painting windows.  It is burning 100% core on just dispatching the delegates.  The invoke queue keeps growing without bounds, the user however runs out of patience before your program runs out of memory so an actual crash is rare.

You need to fix this by calling ReportProgress() less frequent.  Keep in mind that you only need to achieve *one* goal, keeping the eyes of the user entertained.  That's very easy, your output turns into an unreadable blur around 20 updates per second.  Giving you an easy 50x safety margin.

Comment: makes a lot of sense what you say. I don't quite get your last point "Giving you an easy 50x safety margin." What do you suggest I do to smooth it down? Should I report every 50 inserts?

Comment: No.  You should not call ReportProgress more often than ~20 times per second.  Exactly how you do that is up to you, using Environment.TickCount is a logical way, but focusing on *usability* is the primary way to get there.  Give meaningful progress feedback, something the user can actually *read*, and this problem solves itself.

Comment: can you show me a basic example of using Environment.TickCount to decide whether to ReportProgress or not so I could accept you as a correct answer please?

Answer (score -1):

This is because of UI thread in blocking the execution thread (while access the UI controls). Try the below code

```
        switch (e.ProgressPercentage)
        {
            case -1:
                listBoxMessages.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                    listBoxMessages.Items.Add(e.UserState.ToString());
                    listBoxMessages.Items.Add("");
                }));
                break;
            case 100:
                listBoxMessages.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                    listBoxMessages.Items.RemoveAt(listBoxMessages.Items.Count - 1);
                    listBoxMessages.Items.Add(e.UserState.ToString());
                }));
                break;
            default:
                listBoxMessages.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                   listBoxMessages.Items.RemoveAt(listBoxMessages.Items.Count - 1);
                   listBoxMessages.Items.Add(string.Format(e.UserState.ToString()));
                }));
                progressBar.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                progressBar.PerformStep();
                }));
                break;
        }
```